# MSSQL Insatalation error - perflib 2.0 counter removal failed with exit code 2

Tags: sql-server, installation

I am trying to install SQL2019 Server. 
comming This Error. cant Installation
[image]

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Setup

The following error has occurred:

> PerfLib 2.0 counter removal failed with exit code 2. Command line:
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\unlodctr.exe /m:hkengperfctr.xml from directory
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Shared.

Answer (score 1):

•   There is incomplete uninstallation of SQL server and we are not able to install in SQL server in your PC  due to below errors.
•   Database Engine services Failed
•   PerfLib 2.0 counter removal failed with exit code 2.
•   The MOF compiler could not connect with the WMI server.

[image]

[image]

[image]

•   Below is troubleshooter link and search window

[image]

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d
•   Here, you have to download the troubleshooter in your PC

•   After download, you have to run the file and you will get below window & click Next

•   Choose based on issue, its related to Installation or Uninstallation

•   Choose one by one all relevant SQL Server content and uninstall, it will repeat each time for one item. Once you have done with all SQL server content, then only uninstall successful. Now you have good to install and without any issue.

[image]